# Syntax error when close div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have below code in WordPress template:

```
</header><?php

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->menu_main_menu();

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->breadcrumb(); ?>

<div class="container"><?php
Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();

?>
```

and when i want close opened dive like below, it show me syntax error:

```
</header><?php

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->menu_main_menu();

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->breadcrumb(); ?>

<div class="container"><?php
Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();
</div>
?>
```

i want close dive cause i want create bootstrap row like below, but i see syntax error:

```
</header><?php

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->menu_main_menu();

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->breadcrumb(); ?>

<div class="container"><?php
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
hello world
</div>
</div>
</div>
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this; You were getting errors because you had raw html within php.

```
</header><?php

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->menu_main_menu();

Better_Mag::generator()->blocks()->breadcrumb(); ?>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
<?php
Better_Mag::generator()->get_main_slider();
?>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-6">
hello world
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, worked, just i used bootstrap cause i wanted they going side by side, but "hello world" goes under it, screenshot: http://prntscr.com/cxfo3d

Comment: Good to hear. Sometimes formatting can be the root of the problem.